# Adjusting/adding to timer output using Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, timer, swift3

I'm making my first apps in Xcode using Swift 3 and I'm coming up a bit of a challenge with making a timer. So far, I have an app that counts down and can reset to a pre-defined time. My next step is to let the user adjust the start time using single swipe up to add seconds to the timer, swipe down to remove seconds from the timer.

My code so far:

```
import UIKit

class StopWatchViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var timerLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.timerLabel.text = timeString(time: TimeInterval(seconds))
    }

    var seconds = 180 //This is start time in seconds 180 = 3mins
    var timer = Timer()
    var isTimerRunning = false

    func updateTimer() {
        if seconds < 2 {
            timer.invalidate()
            self.timerLabel.text = "Stop!"
        } else {
            seconds -= 1
            timerLabel.text = timeString(time: TimeInterval(seconds))
        }
    }

    func runTimer() {
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: (#selector(StopWatchViewController.updateTimer)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        isTimerRunning = true
    }

    func singleTapped(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        //Start Timer
        if isTimerRunning == false {
            runTimer()
        }
    }


    func timeString(time:TimeInterval) -> String {
        let minutes = Int(time) / 60 % 60
        let seconds = Int(time) % 60
        return String(format:"%02i:%02i", minutes, seconds)
    }

    func longPress(_ sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
       //Pause
    if isTimerRunning == true {
            timer.invalidate()
            isTimerRunning = false
        }
    }

    func doubleTapped(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        //Double Tap Reset
        timer.invalidate()
        seconds = 180
        timerLabel.text = timeString(time: TimeInterval(seconds))
        isTimerRunning = false
    }

    func addsecond() {
        if isTimerRunning == false {
        //timer plus second
            timerLabel.text = timeString(time: TimeInterval(seconds)+1)
        }
    }

    func singleSwipeUp(_ sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {   
        //Add seconds using swipe up
        timer.invalidate()
        addsecond()

    }
}
```

This works as a timer with a pre-defined time (3 minutes) but it does not let the user adjust the time using swipes up and down. It currently will add only one second to the display but this does not effect the non-activated timer as soon as it's restarted. I'm mainly looking for hints with the function addsecond.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a variable `seconds` which you use to track when your timer will complete, and also display into your timerLabel.

Your `singleSwipeUp(_:)` calls `addSecond()`, which changes the `timerLabelText`, but does not change the `seconds` variable that actually controls the timer.

(You should follow the swift convention of naming functions using lowerCamelCase, where the first letter is lower case, and the beginning of each following word in the function name is in upper case, so `addsecond()` should be named `addSecond()` instead.

Class names and types should be named in UpperCamelCase, where all words in the name are capitalized, including the first letter.)

Rewrite `addSecond()` as follows:

```
func addsecond() {
    if isTimerRunning == false {
        //Increment seconds, then install the new value in timerLabel
        seconds += 1
        timerLabel.text = timeString(time: TimeInterval(seconds))
    }
}
```